# What is the difference between "gambo" and "kruro"?

Tags: word-usage

I've heard people using both *gambo* or *kruro* for *leg*. Is there a difference between them? Somebody said that maybe one of the two is only from the knee and down. Is this correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#gambo):

> **gamb/o:** Tuto de la malsupra membro de homo.

Translation:

> **gamb/o:** The entire lower member of a human.

And, for [*kruro*](http://vortaro.net/#kruro)

> ***krur/o:**
>
> 1 Malsupra membro de dupiedulo, antaŭa aŭ malantaŭa membro de kvarpiedulo, aŭ membro de artropodo
>
> 2 ❤ (crus) Parto de la malsupra (aŭ malantaŭa) membro de la vertebruloj, inter genuo k piedo
>
> 3 Analoga parto ĉe objekto

Translation:

> **krur/o:**
>
> 1 Lower member [limb] of a biped, front or hind member of a quadruped, or a member of an arthropod
>
> 2 ❤ (crus) Part of the lower (or hind) member of vertebrates, between knee and foot
>
> 3 Analogous part of an object

The ❤ indicates use in biology and histology. So, at least according to PIV, the differences are:

- *Gambo* always refers to the entire lower limb, while *kruro* in some contexts is only the part between knee and foot.
- *Gambo* is only used for human legs, while *kruro* can also refer to the legs of animals, arthropods, and objects such as furniture.

I have also noticed that *kruro* is more commonly used, even for human legs.

Comment: Note that _gamb/_ is a neologism (neither Fundamenta, nor official), while _krur/_ is Fundamenta. That's something to keep in mind. Anyway, in decades of Esperanto I've never used _gambo_ and I don't remember hearing it. Just stick to _krur_. By the way, when citing definitions the status of the word should be listed. In Esperanto it **is** part of the definition.

Answer (score 7):

Modern dictionaries assert that the *kruro* is the shank (knee to ankle), at least in medical contexts, while the *gambo* is the whole leg including the foot.

However, this is a modern distinction and older Esperanto text (all from Zamenhof's time) only uses *kruro*. I think the Ido word *gambo* may have been imported by Johannes Dietterle for his visual dictionary but I'm not sure.

Comment: I agree with the first line. I disagree with the second line. The trouble with "older" text is not that they don't use *gambo* but that it's defined differently in all different places. Even some newer books get it wrong.

I also recall that human/non-human factors in to some of the definitions.

Comment: Looks like the "second line" has been edited. Much better now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is such disagreement between words like *gambo* & *kruro* is really detrimental to the widespread acceptance of Esperanto. There has to be a clear distinction between the two. If one is only a part of the leg & the other is the leg as a whole, that distinction should be made. The same thing goes for *vidi* / *rigardi* / *spekti*. There is a good Esperanto dictionary that I use called [glosbe](https://www.glosbe.com/en/eo) that allows you to compare all of the similar meanings of a word in many languages. It is contributed to by users so it's *not* 100% perfect, but I haven't found anything else better. **Glosbe does list *gambo* as the whole leg & *kruro* as the lower half of the leg.** With the word for *leg* specifically though, The word *piedo* is also listed as a translation. That makes me think of toki pona. The toki pona word *noka* means foot or leg & the which one it is must be guessed by context. If you're not familiar with toki pona it only has ~125 words so this kind of thing happens a lot in toki pona.

Comment: No, it isn't detrimental. For specific contexts, like medicine and biology, you need a way to specify (which kristan seems to have done), but for everyday use you don't. There are languages which use one word for everything below one's hip, and that's often enough.

Comment: I suppose I didn't word it clearly. What I meant is that there are likely a lot of people who  don't understand the difference between gambo & kruro, as with vidi/rigardi/spekti. What is detrimental is there being such apparent ambiguity because people aren't being taught the difference between similar words & when to use one over another. It's the same thing as *look* vs *see* vs *view* in English.

Comment: Andrew Woods gives in his answer a plausible explanation. You can use _kruro_ in most non-medical contexts for every part. Heck, I don't know what's the difference between _gambo_ and _kruro_ or _foot_ and _leg_ without resorting to an anatomy book.

Comment: That's why we have an language academy that will let new words be considered official based on their meaning. That's why it is SOOOO important to list definitions of Esperanto roots with their current status. Otherwise people might end up asking the difference between _printempo_ and _primavero_ or, things like _presi_ and _printi_.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas Again at the risk of beating a dead horse, my point is if there is a need to consult a medical book to figure out the difference between two words, then the best choice is to only use one word. Having one word be only for people & another word for people & animals is ridiculous. It's like German having 6 ways of saying "the".

Comment: @jastako, as Eduardo pointed out, _kruko_ is a fundamenta word, while _gambo_ is a neologism. And therefore [Bona lingvo](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/Ssv:_G) recommends not to use the former but the latter. I am all in favour for _kruro_, and all I was trying to say that if there is a need to separate term in some specific fields, like medicine and biology, then you might need _gambo_. Generally you do not need it.